# Location for Android Small / Contextual Icons

Tags: android, icons, android-icons

I read  [official iconographic article](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/design/style/iconography.html#small-contextual) and I don't understand in which directory I should place small/contextual icons. As understand for action bar icons I should use drawable-XXXX but info for small icons wasn't mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have folders such as:

```
drawable
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-xxxhdpi
```

under "res" folder. Any file which has no specific dimensions can go into "drawable". You can also have "raw" folder under res, which can be used to any other file type.

For more info see this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `small/contextual` icons the same way as the `ActionBar` icons. Just put the secific sizes to your `drawable-xxxx` folder.

Theres also a good article ["Multi Screen Support"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) that should be read.

And here is an [Android Design Icons Pack](https://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20131106.zip) where you can have graphic buttons that represent the most important actions for users.